# Use the "Starts with" selector in less

Tags: css, less

Lets say i have a div like

```
<div class="col-d-1 col-m-5">some content</div>
```

I want to select the div. Normaly no problem... My problem is, there is more css that acts on this div. So I dont want to use !important. I try to use more than one selector to keep this one "important". Now i know there will be a `col-m-` but i dont know the value.... even if its 1, 2, 3 or what ever...

Actually in CSS i would use

```
.col-d-1 [class^='col-m-'] {
    background: red;
}
```

something like this to select my `col-d-1` having some `col-m-`

But how to convert this to less ?

I thought

```
.col-d-1 {
    &.col-m-* {
        background: red;
    }
}
```

But nothing i tried works ^^

Any suggestions ?

Or is this less allready ?

Comment: Of course it doesn’t work if you change the selector type ... the attribute selector is still the attribute selector, even when you use LESS ... you can not just substitute the class selector for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
.col-d-1 {
    &[class*='col-m-'] {
        background: red;
    }
}
```

[codepen example](https://codepen.io/sol_b/pen/baxOQq)

Comment: This is preferred to the `caret` option as it selects *regardless* of class order.

Answer (score 2):

Well, LESS does recognise CSS, so keep it unchanged should work.

The other option is just combine it using the raw selector:

```
.col-d-1 {
    &[class*='col-m-'] {
        background: red;
    }
}
```

Because you are pattern-matching on the class attribute, not checking if a class within it starts with `col-m-`, you need to use the contains selector `*=`, no the starts-with selector.